# Docusign Node SDK - EnvelopesAPI.createEnvelope() failing with INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, docusignapi

I'm trying to use the Docusign node sdk to create an envelope from a template that already exists in the Docusign developer account.

However I always get a 400 response with this message: `{"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER","message":"The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Query parameter 'from_date' must be set to a valid DateTime or 'envelope_ids', 'folder_ids' or 'transaction_ids' must be specified."}`

The full error object shows that the request being made is to GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes. Which I imagine means it is trying to return the envelope that should have just been created.

I can't see how I can influence this call as it's not called directly.

The process I'm following:

1. Getting a jwt access token
2. Initialising the envelopes API
3. Creating an envelope definition (the templateId variable matches the mid of the template in Docusign)
4. The create request is sent (the account id is the same one shown in the developer account under Apps and Keys)

The code in question:

```
      this.dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader(
        'authorization',
        `Bearer ${response.body.access_token}`,
      );
      const envelopesAPI = new EnvelopesApi(this.dsApiClient);
      const envelopeDefinition: EnvelopeDefinition = {
        templateId,
        templateRoles: [
          {
            name: profile.displayName,
            email: profile.defaultEmailAddress,
            clientUserId: profile.personId,
            roleName: 'Demo'
          },
        ],
        status: 'sent',
      };

      const envelope = await envelopesAPI.createEnvelope(
        this.configService.get('docusign.auth.accountId'),
        {
          envelopeDefinition: envelopeDefinition,
        },
      );
```

However other APIs via the sdk such as

```
      await templatesApi.listTemplates(this.configService.get('docusign.auth.accountId'))
```

Return a 200 response and expected data.

Comment: The issue was that the base URL coming from the env file was http not https. So my bad, but still odd that that it causes a redirect to a different request ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a `roleName` for any role in your `templateRoles` in order to send an envelope based on a template.
So your code should be like this:

```
  this.dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader(
    'authorization',
    `Bearer ${response.body.access_token}`,
  );
  const envelopesAPI = new EnvelopesApi(this.dsApiClient);
  const envelopeDefinition: EnvelopeDefinition = {
    templateId,
    templateRoles: [
      {
        name: profile.displayName,
        email: profile.defaultEmailAddress,
        clientUserId: profile.personId,
        roleName: 'yourRoleName'
      },
    ],
    status: 'sent',
  };

  const envelope = await envelopesAPI.createEnvelope(
    this.configService.get('docusign.auth.accountId'),
    {
      envelopeDefinition: envelopeDefinition,
    },
  );
```

See more information here - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-template-remote/

Comment: thanks, I have added a roleName but still get the same response (a GET I'm not making throwing a 400). Any other ideas?

Comment: Please enable API logs and see what API call is the GET that gives you 400 error

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJYTDcc7cZw

Comment: I'm not sure if this is all the code you have, if the error is coming from GET call, then you must have more code somewhere. Can you debug and see which API calls it is?

Comment: I commented this above. 
"The issue was that the base URL coming from the env file was http not https. So my bad, but still odd that that it causes a redirect to a different request, which then fails ¯_(ツ)_/¯ "

Comment: I still don't understand which call gives an issue. Would you mind trying to download our quickstart code (Node.js) and run the create template and create envelope from template code examples? see if these work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I won't have time to do that. But the code below is the exact call that caused the issue.

My best guess is that if ApiClient.setBasePath() is provided with a http url then when an api request is made it tries to redirect the request to https but it redirects to the GET request when I was making a POST and the GET was therefore invalid.

```const envelope = await envelopesAPI.createEnvelope(
    this.configService.get('docusign.auth.accountId'),
    {
      envelopeDefinition: envelopeDefinition,
    },
  )```

Comment: This code makes a POST not a GET request, which is why I find this odd. How do you know it does a GET?

Comment: I know because the full response shows the path and method being made. Yes it's very odd but I was able to consistently produce this problem by having the base path set to http://demo.docusign.net/restapi. Changing it https://demo.docusign.net/restapi fixed it and it worked perfectly. To me it looks like the http to https redirect redirects to the wrong method with this endpoint, but I don't have enough knowledge to know that for sure.

Comment: The two urls are identical,  I'm confused

Comment: They aren't, one is http and the other is https

Comment: Https is correct

Comment: That's what my comment is saying. It worked once the env was switched to https however the API still behaves weirdly if given a http base URL, it incorrectly redirects

Comment: Why would you use http? To what purpose?

Comment: It was a typo not intentional. My point is that the API responds in a strange way if that is provided. It redirects to a GET request which then fails. That means it can be hard to even spot that http is being used.

Comment: ok, now I understand. You would like the SDK to explicitly give a useful error in this case.
Would you mind going to feedback.docusign.com and enter this feedback for our team?